# WCF Throttling with Multiple ServiceContracts

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service with 14-15 Service contracts defined using netTcpBinding and no security or reliable sessions.

I have enabled Throttling as a behavior and have not defined an InstanceContextMode so I can assume it's a PerSession instancing. (I've read that even if I changed it to say PerCall it would ignore it since netTcpBinding is "sessionful", can someone confirm this?)

```
      <serviceThrottling
               maxConcurrentCalls="100"
               maxConcurrentSessions="300"
             />
```

My question really is, what should my settings be in this case for each service? 
and are there implications for performance and deadlocks with this many contracts defined in 1 running service on a server?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ServiceThrottling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx) is a behaviour for a service and applies to a service.

As such, you can define different such behaviours and apply different throttling to your services - perhaps prevent a DOS attack.

General approach to Throttling is "If it aint't broke, don't fix it.". In most cases you do not need throttling. Throttling only helps if you have a shared resource (your website and services run on the same server) and you do not want your services to suffocate your website.

**Throttling is not gonna cause or help with deadlocks.**

Comment: When you say you do not need throttling, are you suggesting to keep the default throttling or override it?